# How do I keep a type as generic in f#?

Tags: generics, dynamic, f#, inference, discriminated-union

I'm struggling with setting up an f# function so that that it can accept type (from c#) `Dictionary<keys, dynamic>` where keys is just type enum and dynamic would be a scruct type which holds parameters.

My f# function looks like this:

```
    let func (stores: Dictionary<keys, 'values>) =

        let newObj1State = object1.addOne(stores.[keys.0])
        let newObj2State = object2.addOne(stores.[keys.1])

        let newSystemState = new Dictionary<keys, 'values>()
        newSystemState.Add(keys.0, newObj1State);
        newSystemState.Add(keys.1, newObj2State);
        newSystemState
```

The problem that I'm having is that when the f# compiler runs the function it sees that `'values` is being referenced as type Object1 first so it assumes that `'values` is of type Object1 and throws this error to the calling command.

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Types.keys, dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Types.keys, Types.Object1>
```

Is there a way I can keep `'values` as generic so it doesn't infer a datatype from code?

Comment: You can specify the type in the function declaration and when you call - same as CSharp - `let func<'values> (stores: Dictionary<keys, 'values>) =`. Then you call like this `func<dynamic> stores`.

Comment: F# normally tries to make generic as much as it can. It could be either the "addOne" method is constraining the type to "Object1" especially if the addOne method isn't generic itself. If addOne is generic on its input argument then it has to do with the actual instance of object1 and object2. Passing them in as arguments to the function should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `object1.AddOne` probably expects an `Object1` as its argument, which is triggering the compiler to infer the type of `values as `Object1`. If this is the case then you can simply replace `object1.AddOne(stores.[keys.0])` with `object1.AddOne(box stores.[keys.0])`.

The function `box` basically tells the compiler "upcast what I'm giving you to `obj`". Upcasting something before passing it to `addOne` lets the compiler know it shouldn't assume that the type of `values matches exactly the signature of `addOne`.